# SQL Pivot with Datetime as a Column with quantity fields

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, pivot

I have a SQL view on my database to print a report on C# and Itext7 using Lot and PartNumberId to find the results

```
DECLARE @LotId int = '1'
DECLARE @PartNumerId int = '100'

SELECT * FROM vw_report_diarydefects WHERE LotId = @LotId AND PartNumerId = @PartNumerId
```

| Lot | PartNumberId | PartNumber | DefectId | Defect | Qty | SortingDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | WD40 | 1 | Broken | 9 | 2019-10-01 10:31:02.000 |
| 1 | 100 | WD40 | 2 | Paint Scratch | 10 | 2019-10-02 10:31:02.000 |
| 1 | 100 | WD40 | 3 | Swollen | 8 | 2019-10-02 10:31:02.000 |
| 1 | 100 | WD40 | 2 | Paint Scratch | 10 | 2019-10-03 10:31:02.000 |
| 1 | 100 | WD40 | 4 | Bent | 5 | 2019-10-04 10:31:02.000 |

What i want to do is put the SortingDate as columns and add the quantity on them like this:

| Defect | 2019-10-01 10:31:02.000 | 2019-10-02 10:31:02.000 | 2019-10-03 10:31:02.000 | 2019-10-04 10:31:02.000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Broken | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Paint Scratch | 0 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| Swollen | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| Bent | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

I used pivot (my 1st time using it) and i have use this:

```
DECLARE @StuffColumn varchar(max)
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

DECLARE @LotId int = '1'
DECLARE @PartNumerId int = '100'

SELECT @StuffColumn = STUFF((SELECT distinct ','+QUOTENAME(SortingDate)
                        FROM vw_report_diarydefects
                                    WHERE LotId = @LotId AND PartNumerId = @PartNumerId
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SET @SQL = ' select Defect, '+ @StuffColumn +'
         from
         (
            select   SortingDate,Defect,Qty
            from vw_report_diarydefects
            where LotId = ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @LotId, 121)+ ''' and PartNumerId = ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @PartNumerId, 121)+ '''
         )x
         pivot
         (
             Sum(Qty)
             for SortingDate in( '+@StuffColumn+' )
         )p'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Getting just this:

| Defect | Oct 1 2019 10:31AM | Oct 2 2019 10:31AM | Oct 3 2019 10:31AM | Oct 4 2019 10:31AM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Broken | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Paint Scratch | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Swollen | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Bent | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Is there a way to fill the Date Columns with the quantity data? Is my first time using Pivot, i am reading about that instruction but i still have some doubts.

Comment: Don't *inject* your parameters; this opens you up to SQL injection attacked. Dynamic SQL can be parametrised, just like normal SQL, if you execute it properly using `sys.sp_executesql`.

Comment: You probably want `Sum(Qty)` instead of `Count(Qty)`. `Count(Qty)` counts how many quantities are not null. Also use [Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/) to get the format you want. Also apply it to `for SortingDate in ...`

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, i will start lookin for `code sys.sp_executesql`

Comment: Hello @OlivierJacot-Descombes i already added  `code Sum(Qty)`  but still got NULL on all the rows instead of the QTY data, i will try to look what i am missing on the QUERY. Thanks.

Comment: Your pivot is good. It seems to me that the filter expression of `for` isn't working. Can you do `Print @Sql` and put it here.

Comment: Hello @vendettamit The Print Result Is:

`select Defect, [Oct  1 2019 10:31AM],[Oct  2 2019 10:31AM],[Oct  3 2019 10:31AM],[Oct  4 2019 10:31AM]
         from
         (
            select   SortingDate,Defect,Qty
            from vw_report_diarydefects
   where LotId = '3023' and PartNumerId = '1626'
         )x
         pivot
         (
             SUM(Qty)
             for SortingDate in( [Oct  1 2019 10:31AM],[Oct  2 2019 10:31AM],[Oct  3 2019 10:31AM],[Oct  4 2019 10:31AM] )
         )p

(4 rows affected)

Completion time: 2021-07-01T12:57:00.9018459-05:00
`

Comment: The issue is with `QuoteName` converting date to different date format causing a mismatch. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found. The way the `Quotename` is changing the date format is the issue. Change your @StuffColumn data to convert to varchar first and then Quote it.

```
SELECT @StuffColumn = STUFF((SELECT distinct ','+QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),SortingDate, 121))
                        FROM vw_report_diarydefects
                                    WHERE Lot = @LotId AND PartNumberId = @PartNumerId
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bae23/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication193
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Lot",typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("PartNumberId",typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("PartNumber",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DefectId",typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Defect",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("SortingDate", typeof(DateTime));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 100, "WD40", 1, "Broken", 9, DateTime.Parse("2019-10-01 10:31:02.000")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 100, "WD40", 2, "Paint Scratch", 10, DateTime.Parse("2019-10-02 10:31:02.000")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 100, "WD40", 3, "Swollen", 8, DateTime.Parse("2019-10-02 10:31:02.000")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 100, "WD40", 2, "Paint Scratch", 10, DateTime.Parse("2019-10-03 10:31:02.000")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 100, "WD40", 4, "Bent", 5, DateTime.Parse("2019-10-04 10:31:02.000")});


            DateTime[] dates = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("SortingDate")).OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().ToArray();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("Defect");
            foreach (DateTime date in dates)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(date.ToString(), typeof(int));
            }

            foreach(var defect in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Defect")))
            {
                DataRow newRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                newRow["Defect"] = defect.Key;
                foreach (DataRow row in defect)
                {
                    int qty = row.Field<int>("Qty");
                    DateTime date = row.Field<DateTime>("SortingDate");
                    newRow[date.ToString()] = qty;
                }
            }

        }
    }
 
}
```