# Create an object from three tables with linq

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

Following three tables I want to create an object so I can display it in a table in the front.
I have to paint a table starting from 3 tables that are in different databases. A main one (the content of the table), another that will be used for the headers of the table (the countries) and another that will be the description of the rows (first column)

The countries table contains a list of countries (30) with a code

The description of the table. Contains a code

The main table contains country code, description code and other information to display in the field and in the field tooltip

Main is table1
Descriptions is table 2
Countries is table 3

[image: finaltable]

I have tried to do it with grupBy but I have not reached the solution

Could you help me guide me, how could I get to the solution

Comment: You may need to create a pivot table in c# code similar to the ones created in excel.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741333/how-to-convert-horizontal-data-into-vertical-from-database-to-datagridview-in-c/45741704#45741704

Comment: Hi, this question was removed

Comment: "grupBy" is illegal. Do you have the same typo in your code? Let us see what you tried.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68212197/sql-pivot-with-datetime-as-a-column-with-quantity-fields/68214685#68214685

Comment: And is table 1 rectangular already or does it need pivoting ?

Comment: It need to pivot, it is a list (description code, countries code, field info and tooltip info)

Comment: The code should be very similar to the datatable input except you get data from a list.  Output could still be a datatable.

Comment: Normally when you pivot and have 5 fields you will group four fields and the 5th field would be the columns.  I've seen cases where OP wanted two fields in the column alternating A/B for each group.

Comment: C# is a language of types, please add the types you are working with and expect, e.g. what are the "tables" - `DataTable`? EF `Sets`? Something else?

Comment: All types are strings

Comment: table 1 is a object list